# How do I draw the graph of $h(x) = f(-x+2)$ from the graph of $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Let's say we have a function $f(x)$

How do I draw $h(x)$ from $f(x)$ if you knew that $h(x) = f(-x+2)$?

Comment: Why not try a couple of examples? $f(x) = x + 5$ becomes $h(x) = -x + 7$. Or $f(x) = x^2$ becomes $h(x) = x^2-4x+4$. Draw these graphs. Draw a few more. See if you can tell how one becomes the other. Or simplify. What if $h(x) = f(-x)$? What if $h(x) = f(x+2)$? What happens then? Your answer ought to be some combination of these two, doesn't it?

Comment: @Arthur The thing is that I'm so frustrated because I made a stupid mistake on the exam yesterday. I just wanted to hear some good news because I didn't believe it at first.

Comment: The punchline will involve the words "*reflect across*" and "*horizontal shift*" or equivalent phrases.

Comment: @JMoravitz I might have got 1 thing correct in all this mess. Can you state what's the horizontal shift?

Comment: $2$, either to the left or to the right depending on if you shift before reflecting or if you reflect before shifting.

Comment: @JMoravitz So the shift vector is (2, 0) right?

Comment: See several examples [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/functions/translations.html).

Answer (score 3):

First find $f(x+2)$ which is a shift of $2$ units to the left.

Then find $f(-x+2)$ by reflecting the graph of $f(x+2)$ about the x-axis.